# Testflight, universal app is not installable on iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, testflight

I'm having a strange issue with test flight.
I'm building an universal app, and I've already tested working both on iPad air and iPhone.

I've uploaded a build to test flight to distribute it to beta testers, and on the permissions page I see that is universal, and in the provisioning profile all the devices of my testers are included.
But, when I browse to testflightapp.com with an iPad to install the app, it appears on the list of the incompatible apps.

How can I fix this? Is there some check I can make?

Thanks

Comment: Have you included the correct provisioning profile that the device is on for both the app and for test flight?

Comment: Yes, I use the same provisioning for development, and on the permission page I see that all the devices are included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its just the provisional files is not updated  correctly.It happened to me lately, when you add new devices in Apple Profile, you need to update the provisional files.There are also chances that multiple provisional files are stored in you're KeyChain Access.If that happened , delete the oldest one and try once more.

(PS: i know my descriptions are less, i will update it soon)

Comment: Thanks, I regenerated the provisioning and worked..I think test flight is a little buggy

Comment: Oh yes..  i find the issue is with the apple provisioning profile update ..it got hell lot of complexities..